# How to replace snprintf with std::format_to_n elegantly?

Tags: c++, format

I am learning c++20, I found `std::format` is a good feature. from my simple test, it's faster than `snprintf`.

so I want to replace `snprintf` with `std::format_to_n`.

the origin method is:

```
const std::string & my_string = "haha";
double i = 0.1;
char buff[256];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s + %lf", my_string, i);
```

the new `std::format_to_n` is simple:

```
char buff[256]
std::format_to_n(buff, sizeof(buff), "{} + {}", my_string, i);
```

the annoying part is:

i need to add a terminator for buff, the recommend method is:

```
auto r = std::format_to_n(buff, sizeof(buff), "{} + {}", my_string, i);
*r.out = '\0';
```

I think this is ugly, so I tried this:

```
std::format_to_n(buff, sizeof(buff), "{} + {}\0", my_string, i);
```

But i got mess code for buff if i print it.

Could you help on this? Is there any elegant method can do this?

Comment: And you don't want to `std::format` to `std::string`, right?

Comment: I would recommend to use `fmt` library instead `std::format`. C++20 picked small amour of `fmt` functionality and support of `std::format` from different compilers is not great. `fmt` will work everywhere.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450200/forcing-format-to-n-to-use-terminating-zero